# How to (sinon) stub an external module function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon, stubbing

```
import fileType from 'file-type';

export function checkFileType(input){
if(fileType(input).mime === 'image/png'){
// do something;
return 'Yes It is PNG';
} else {
// do something;
return 'No. It is not PNG';
}
}
```

I want to write unit test case for the above method, in that I want to stub 'fileType(input)'.

I have tried to do like below in my test file.

```
import * as fileTypeObj from 'file-type'; 
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe(__filename, () => {
  let sandbox;
  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

it('test the function', async () => {
    sandbox.stub(fileTypeObj, 'default').withArgs('someinput').returns({mime: 'image/png'});
    await checkFileType('someinput)';
})
})
```

But it is not working as expected (Not stubbing ... making the direct actual call).
Please help me to stub properly and test.

Comment: The easier solution would be to use the proxyquire library. You can find the examples for it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire#example

Comment: This `sandbox.stub(fileTypeObj, 'default')` is expected to work, due to how ES modules work. What exactly does 'it is not working as expected' mean? The code doesn't contain the actual test.

Comment: @estus Pls find the updated test suite.

Comment: I see. This would work if `file-type` were real ES module. This is https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type , isn't it? That's CJS module that is likely imported through module interop. It doesn't have `default`. Use the ways that are specific to CJS module mocking, such as proxyquire mentioned above.

Comment: Yes. This is the one https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type

Answer (score 1):

`file-type` package export function as default, so it is a bit harder to mock with just `Sinon`. We must involve `proxyquire` to make the testing easier.

This is how the test looks like using `proxyquire`

```
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('unit test', function() {
  let fileTypeStub;
  let src;

  beforeEach(function() {
    fileTypeStub = sinon.stub();
    src = proxyquire('./path-to-your-src', { 'file-type': fileTypeStub }); 
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    sinon.restore();
  })

  it('returns yes for PNG', async function() {
    fileTypeStub.returns({ mime: 'image/png'});  

    const response = await src.checkFileType('any input');
    expect(response).to.equal('Yes It is PNG')
  });

  it('returns no for not PNG', async function() {    
    fileTypeStub.returns({ mime: 'image/jpg'});

    const response = await src.checkFileType('any input');
    expect(response).to.equal('No. It is not PNG')
  });
});
```

Hope it helps